# Find all values of $n, m \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ where ${n \choose m}=1984$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

> Find all $n, m \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ where ${n \choose m}=1984$

I tried so hard on this question in the past couple of days I couldn't achieve anything, which forced me to resort to the guess and check method, but even that was hard. I tried to convert it to $\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}=1984$ but couldn't reach anything. I also attempted to find $1984=x!$ but there was no value for $x$. I was wondering if I could receive some help on this question if possible. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $31\mid 1984$, $n\geq 31$ must hold.  If $m\geq 3$ or $n-m\geq 3$, then
$$\binom{n}{m}\geq \binom{n}{3} \geq \binom{31}{3}=4495>1984\,.$$
Therefore, $m\leq 2$ or $n-m\leq 2$.  Thus, you are left with not so many choices now.

> All solutions are $(n,m)=(1984,1)$ and $(n,m)=(1984,1983)$.

Comment: Could you please further explain the step where you said that since $31|1984$, therefore, $n \geq 31$

Comment: You have $1984=\displaystyle\binom{n}{m}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-m+1)}{m!}$, or $$31\cdot 2^4\cdot m!=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-m+1)\,.$$  Since $31$ is prime, it has to divide one of the factors $n$, $n-1$, $n-2$, $\ldots$, $n-m+1$.  As you should know, if $a$ and $b$ are positive integers such that $a\mid b$, then $a\leq b$.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since $31$ is prime ,it has to devide one of the factors $n,(n-1),(n-2),\cdots,(n-k+1).$ but why $31$ must only devide $n?$